# Android volume control to allow low volume

Tags: android, audio, volume-control

I am looking for an Android app that allows me to lower the volume below the regular 1-bar.

I have tried [Fine Volume Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=opotech.finevolumev2) and it has the functionality I need, however, I am looking for a free and/or open source replacement that has the same functionality.